# GitHub Actions: auto-PR on some files update?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm very new to GitHub Actions/CI/CD, and I want to know whether it is possible to automate the following scenario:

> I have a local script that makes use of some APIs to download some files onto my local machine. My current status is that: I have to run the script every day to check whether the content of these files is updated or not. If some of those files got updated then I need to add those changes into a new branch and push it to a repository as a PR.

My trying: My idea is that since it's possible to compare the hash of the downloaded files to know whether any of those got updated. The next thing to do is to make this into an event to trigger some action?

If it's possible could you share some resources/tutorials about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I tested something similar on GitHub to understand how the CI/CD GitHub actions works.

the script is based on an SQLite DataBase which is updated automatically each time (automatic git push). And it uses Github Secrets to store encrypted Tokens/Passwords.

You can find my scheduler in the follow link: https://github.com/noweh/project-marvel-memories/blob/master/.github/workflows/run-schedule.yml.

you can find more information directly in the github documentation.

Here for the Github actions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows.

And here for the Github encrypted secrets: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-an-environment